# Detect when `fseek()` goes beyond end of file

Tags: c, stdio, fseek

In `<stdio.h>`, the function `fseek()` seems allowed to skip way beyond the end of its file handler, without producing any error code.

While I can understand the behavior when the `FILE*` handler is set to `"w"` write, since it seems to allow writing sparse files, I don't understand the point of such a feature when it's `"r"` read-only.

Anyway, as a consequence, it's not possible to detect that end of file was overshot with `fseek()`, and next attempt to `fread()` simply returns `0`, as if end of file was just reached normally.

What could be a work around to detect that `fseek()` overshot past the end of file ?

Comment: Show your code, please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ... I don't understand the point of such a feature when it's "r" read-only.

I don't think that this is an intended feature but I think that it was simply easier to implement this behavior in the operating system (not in the C libraries).

And if you don't call `fread()` immediately after `fseek()`, another program may append data to the file between the two function calls, so the new file pointer is no longer after the end of the file when you call `fseek()`.

(I just checked that this really works under Linux and I think it would work under Windows and MacOS, too.)

> What could be a work around to detect that fseek() overshot past the end of file?

You could check the file size by setting the file pointer to the end using `fseek(..., 0, SEEK_END);` and reading the file pointer back using `ftell()`.

Then you know the size of the file and may compare the new file pointer (that you pass to `fseek()`) to the size of the file "manually" (in an `if()...else` check).

Comment: So, essentially, know the size of the file beforehand, so one has something to compare to, though in a way which is tracked independently from `fseek()`

Comment: @Cyan: As this answer notes in its first parts, files do not generally have fixed sizes. So you should not attempt to “know the size of the file beforehand” (except possibly for purposes of estimating memory allocation as long as your program is prepared to adapt for changes). The proper method for detecting when there is no data available to be read is to check the return status of a read call.